# Free and Paid App, does it have to be 2 seperate app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am integrating ads in my android app, but a thought came up, do I need to create a free and paid app, one with ads and locked features whilst another one with unlocked features, and I also need help on a tutorial to add in app purchases, all tutorials I keep finding advise me to first upload my app to google play, is that the only way? how do i fix bugs if I begin by uploading my app?

Comment: What have you done so far? What research have you found out?

Comment: you could create a non-consumable IAP item and "unlock" the ad free version. It's quite simple.

Comment: @Geoff according to my research most developers make 2 apps, but like the question states is it necessary ?

Comment: @Cabrra would you please help me with a sample tutorial, this is my first time doing this i have no reference

Comment: To manage the billing inventory you need a IAB -> https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin/wiki/How-to-use-OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin-with-Google-Play This is fairly easy to use. I'll paste a pseudo code in a response to guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use same application as both free and paid but you can differentiate by IN APP:

Here is another blog post explaining In App Purchase:[Link](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/)

[image]

Comment: you are a life saver

Answer (score 2):

This is the IAB (In-App Billing) solution. You'd need to tweak and set it up but the functionality is clear. [source](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/759518/how-to-design-a-remove-ads-option-in-android-unity.html)

```
 function Awake()
 {
     SetupAds();
 }

 function SetupAds()
 {
     if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("AdFree"))
         return;

     // Setup your ads here
 }

 function RemoveAds()
 {
     if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("AdFree"))
         print("Ads already removed");
     else{
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("AdFree", 1);
         PlayerPrefs.Save();

         // destroy/disable all your ad objects here
     }
 }

 function RestorePurchases()
 {
     if (IsProductPurchased("ProductId"))
         RemoveAds();
 }
```